# AWS Windows Ec2 instance not executing userdata

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got an ec2 instance running Windows Server 2019, on a custom AMI. I took the AMI after installing some software, while the instance is running.

The userdata is formatted like so:

```
<powershell>
//Powershell Script
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

When I check the userdata execution log, it shows this:

> 2022/05/03 11:05:41Z: Userdata execution begins
> 2022/05/03 11:05:42Z: Zero or more than one  tag was not provided
> 2022/05/03 11:05:42Z: Sending telemetry bool: IsUserDataScheduledPerBoot
> 2022/05/03 11:05:42Z: Unregistering the persist scheduled task
> 2022/05/03 11:05:45Z: Zero or more than one  tag was not provided
> 2022/05/03 11:05:45Z: Zero or more than one  tag was not provided
> 2022/05/03 11:05:45Z: Zero or more than one  tag was not provided
> 2022/05/03 11:05:45Z:  tag was provided.. running powershell content
> 2022/05/03 11:05:50Z: Userdata execution done
> 2022/05/03 11:19:15Z: Userdata execution begins
> 2022/05/03 11:19:16Z: Failed to get metadata: The result from http://{{ip address}}/latest/user-data was empty
> 2022/05/03 11:19:23Z: Userdata was not provided
> 2022/05/03 11:19:23Z: Userdata execution done

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing this as part of a CloudFormation template or?

Comment: Nope, just a normal Ec2 in an auto scaling group. Gets created via Terraform launch template (you can still see the user data in the aws console)

Comment: Did you check that the user data is available in the instance metadata? Based on the error, it was not the case `The result from http://{{ip address}}/latest/user-data was empty`

Comment: Running Get-EC2InstanceMetadata -Category UserData in Powershell returns an empty response, so I'll assume no. Which is strange, given that it is viewable on the instance in AWS console

Comment: Checked Ec2Launch log and found this: Failed to get metadata: The result from http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/elastic-gpus/associations/ was empty

Comment: @ethanm912 are you able to find the issue? I am having the same issue. I posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74409522/aws-ec2-not-executing-userdata-after-launch-or-restart