# AWS EC2 not executing userdata after launch or restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, ec2-userdata

Using Terraform I launched windows EC2 instance. We used our own AMI. In terraform I have attached powershell script to userdata while creating the instance. After instance is launched, from AWS console I verified that the instance has the following userdata attached.
[image]

Then I checked the log in `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log` However I do not see any of the output from powershell script. Here is the snippet from the log

```
2022/11/05 06:27:13Z: Begin user data script process.
2022/11/05 06:27:13Z: Unable to parse <persist> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:27:13Z: Sending telemetry bool: IsUserDataScheduledPerBoot
2022/11/05 06:27:13Z: Unregister the scheduled task to persist user data.
2022/11/05 06:27:15Z: Unable to parse <runAsLocalSystem> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:27:15Z: Unable to parse <script> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:27:15Z: Unable to parse <powershellArguments> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:27:15Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2022/11/05 06:27:22Z: User data script completed.
2022/11/05 06:34:45Z: Begin user data script process.
2022/11/05 06:34:45Z: Unable to parse <persist> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:34:45Z: Sending telemetry bool: IsUserDataScheduledPerBoot
2022/11/05 06:34:45Z: Unregister the scheduled task to persist user data.
2022/11/05 06:34:48Z: Unable to parse <runAsLocalSystem> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:34:48Z: Unable to parse <script> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:34:48Z: Unable to parse <powershellArguments> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/11/05 06:34:48Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2022/11/05 06:35:01Z: Message: The output from user data script: Running User Data Script
(host) Running User Data Script

WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Listener

Type            Keys                                Name                                                               
----            ----                                ----                                                               
Container       {Transport=HTTPS, Address=*}        Listener_123xxxxx                                                
Setting up WinRM
(host) setting up WinRM
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is not set up to allow remote access to this machine for management.
The following changes must be made:

...
...
...
2022/11/05 06:35:01Z: User data script completed.
2022/11/09 18:06:10Z: Begin user data script process.
2022/11/09 18:06:10Z: Failed to get metadata: The result from http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data was empty
2022/11/09 18:06:18Z: Launch metadata did not include a user data script.
2022/11/09 18:06:18Z: User data script completed.
```

The log also shows `Failed to get metadata: The result from http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data was empty`
when I browse the url it responded back with above powershell script.

[image]

Is there a setting that we missed on original AMI that is not allowing to run userdata?
Why its not able to run the PS script?

**Update 1**

I ran the following command on the created Instance, and then it worked
`C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 –Schedule`

So may be I need to run this command on the original instance from which the AMI was created and then recreate AMI and use it with terraform.

reference
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-troubleshoot-user-data/
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-windows-run-command-existing/

Comment: There are a couple of messages in the log complaining about the tags that you are using, e.g., `<persist>` and some other it seems. Can this script run elsewhere on a Windows machine without errors?

Comment: The log seems to hint that the same EBS volume persisted across different instances. Tear down the instance, delete it's associated EBS volume, and retry

Comment: @MarkoE yes the script can be executed  manually on the same machine

Comment: @Paolo The original instance from which the AMI was created is still running, is it possible that it is colliding with new instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential solution that solved it for me (you commented on my previous post)

When building the AMI, you need to initially shutdown the system with sysprep. This can be found in the EC2Launch app.

Essentially without sysprep, the resulting EC2 instances will not have the initial networking rules they need on startup.